# How to Change permissions for the file config.php to 444?

Tags: php, configuration

I installed a PHP script in localhost. then it says "Change permissions for the file config.php to 444"
What things do I need to edit in coding to make it read only?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the shell command `chmod 444 config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You must change permissions through terminal.
Open terminal, move to the 'config.php' directory and type: `chmod 444 config.php`

Comment: Thanks but I'm using windows. it gives error for chmod

Comment: Ok, try this command on "CMD": `icacls config.php /grant user:(R)`  **Notes:** user must be your user.  (R) is equivalent to 444 (read only)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php `chmod()` function:

```
chmod('/directory/yourfile', 0444);
```

Or if you want to do it using system commands within php, you can use `shell_exec()` function:(Note that this only works on linux systems)

```
shell_exec('chmod 444 filename');
```